# Where is location of "Related Products" and "Cross-sells" collection of function

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, cross-sells, related-products, locations

I am working admin backend module. I want to know location of `Related Products` and `Cross-sells` product-collections which open when we add a new product from admin panel.

Comment: are you need cross sells & related product collection?

Answer (score 1):

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Crosssell.php
```

`app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Related.php`

These are the location of requested files.